# Html meta tags are not detected when updated with Meta (@angular/platform-browser)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

I am using the sevice Meta from @angular/platform-browser to add dinamically meta tags in my route. When I inspect the page I can see the meta tags but they are not detected by twitter or facebook.
Here is what I did:

I added the meta tag in index.html

```
  <meta name="title" content="test title">
```

then in my component I update the tag:

```
...
constructor(private meta: Meta, private postSearchService: PostSearchService) {}

ngOnInit(){
 this.postSearchService.getPost(this.postName).then((data) => {
  this.data = data;
  this.meta.updateTag({ name: "title", content: data.title });
 });
}
```

The problem is that twitter and facebook do not detect the meta tags:

(here you see that the title does not appear, the same happens if I try to add images).
[image]

But when I inspect the page I can see how the meta tag is updated inside the `<head>`

[image]

I do not know what to do. **Could it be because since I am updating the meta tag after searching the post it takes too long and twitter do not detect it?**

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your meta service can only update the tags after the webpage loads, and Twitter and Facebook might not even load the js used to create your site, the only way around this is to use server-side rendering, at a look at the [Universal Module](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Comment: I will take a look thank you. But then, there is no way to do it using angular only?

Comment: I am working on a similar (same?) problem. I did move the sub-updates to the constructor (instead of ngOnInit), and I'm not using the PostSearchService. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54425816/how-to-get-twitter-to-recognize-angular7-meta-tags-in-a-sub-page-served-by-a-rou